# Getting an exception of initWithCode.. while fetching data from core database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting following exception while fetching data from core database.

***I am able to save data successfully, I can see data in Coredatabase.***

Exception: -
**[error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , -[EntityCurrencies initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001ede880 with userInfo of (null)**

My class structure is like below.

EntityCurrencies+CoreDataProperties.swift

extension EntityCurrencies {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<EntityCurrencies> {
    return NSFetchRequest<EntityCurrencies>(entityName: "EntityCurrencies")
}
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var country_currency: EntityCountry?
```

}

**EntityCountry+CoreDataProperties.swift**

extension EntityCountry {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<EntityCountry> {
    return NSFetchRequest<EntityCountry>(entityName: "EntityCountry")
}

@NSManaged public var currencies: [EntityCurrencies]?
@NSManaged public var languages: [EntityLanguages]?
@NSManaged public var country_currency: EntityCurrencies?
@NSManaged public var country_language: NSSet?
```

}

Below is fetch request code:

```
 let manageObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request:NSFetchRequest<EntityCountry> = EntityCountry.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let result = try manageObjectContext.fetch(request) **/* Crash here */**
```

[image]

Comment: Delete the attribute `currencies` and add a to-many relationship to EntityCurrencies instead with the same name or use the one you already have.

Comment: It is working like charm... but how will get Currencies data in fetch request..

Comment: If you mean from your EntityCountry fetch request then you don't have to do anything, the relationship `currencies` is also a property so read it like a normal property, `let currencies = myCountry.currencies`

Comment: let currency =  data.value(forKey: "country_currency") as? [Currencies]
It is returning nil.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `value(forKey:)` but the result is a Set not an array so my previous example should have been `let currencies = Array(myCountry.currencies)`. I would really recommend that you read up on Core data and/or follow a tutorial so that you understand how Core Data works.

Comment: I am trying by below code
let currency = Array(countryObj.country_currency!) but it is returning 0 element.
I am able to see data in database successfully saved.